Is there a philosophical stance on relativism relating to doing/preventing harm?
Often I feel like other people are doing wrong things (and I think this is a common feeling among many people). My logic for coping with the fact that people in general do wrong things is that

People do things for reasons which might be had for other reasons which ultimately leads back to them wanting to do a thing they think is good,
therefore, people do things for reasons that, from at least someone’s point of view, are good, even if that PoV isn’t mine.

This is just sort of a justification for other people performing actions I personally dislike/disagree with. But I then made the mistake of trying to think about this too hard and arrived at the conclusion that

it is thus not reasonable to try and stop people from doing things because that makes the stopper the villain against them, a person who is trying to stop them from doing good things (in their eyes),

and by direct conclusion,

it is thus not reasonable to try and stop people from doing something that actively harms me/others because they believe that they are doing the right thing and are doing good because of (2), or equivalently because such actions are an instance of things covered by (3), and trying to stop them is tantamount to trying to stop good from being done in the world (even if I don’t personally perceive it as good).

But obviously I can’t deal with that. If someone does something that actively harms me, surely it is because they perceive that it is/leads to a good thing, and I want there to be good things in the world. But I also don’t want to be harmed/let others be harmed. The other option is to force my/someone else’s perceptions of good/bad as a maxim but obviously that’s not good either. My choices seem to be then to

accept everything everyone else does as what it is, including if it hurts me somehow, or
impose my own good/bad definitions on everyone I interact with so that I am justified in protecting myself/others I agree with.

But I’m sure that there must be another way out. Has this problem been considered before by any philosopher more skilled than myself (i.e. any major philosopher), and there/are there any stance/s on how this philosophical issue is to be resolved?

Accepting everything everyone does as 'good' or imposing personal ideas of 'good' on everyone definitely does not sound like an exhaustive list of options. There are norms for what is 'good' that are commonly shared in a society. One does not have to accept them as the 'truth' and can stay a relativist, all that is required is to follow them and expect others to do the same, or else.

There are many theories in various fields that posit "good" things arising emergently as a result of competition and conflict.  Examples include but are not limited to "the invisible hand" in Economics, natural selection in Biology and Democracy in Political Science.
From this perspective, one might reasonably hypothesize an ethical theory through which collective "good" is approximately optimized by individual actors with conflicting aims engaged in active competition.  Many authors on ethics seem to have subscribed to this idea in some degree or another e.g. John Stuart Mill and Ayn Rand (see e.g. pg 28).
